# ASP.NET Data Cache with Azure Redis Cache?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, redis, asp.net-mvc-5

My ASP.NET application is using ASP.NET intrinsic Cache object to store information. How to use Cache intrinsic object with Azure Redis Cache. For Session I can use,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx

But what about `Cache[]`

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman has blogged about this a few days ago. I'm looking forward too, but unfortunately there's no option for Brazil's datacenter yet.

You can see the post in here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TryingRedisCachingAsAServiceOnWindowsAzure.aspx